# WP7 app claims a request to my GAE service produces a 500, GAE claims a 200, where to start?

Tags: google-app-engine, http, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I am writing a Windows Phone 7 app that interfaces with my GAE backend.  For a certain request, the WP7 client claims a 500 error is returned.  I see that request in my GAE logs plain as day, correct contents, time, user agent, everything matches and no errors of any kind, the resulting http code is 200, according to the logs.  But the wp7 app sees a 500.

I don't know where to start - I don't see how the GAE logs could be wrong, but I don't get how the WP7 app could be wrong either.  I'm not running fiddler or anything of the sort.

I don't know where to start with this one...

Comment: I'd start with Fiddler to see what is actually being sent back to the client.

Comment: How do I put fiddler between my device and my service?  I can't reproduce this on the emulator.  Perhaps if I could grab my device's state data from its isolated storage I could reproduce in the emulator, but there's no way to access the device's file system.

Comment: if you know the url being hit, starting fiddler and capturing all traffic should show whenever the emulator makes the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, apologies to WP7, it was not at fault.  What was happening was that I was returning a blobstore blob from GAE that did not exist.  The GAE logs show this as a 200, but with a 0kb reply size, which is what eventually tipped me off.  Would be nice if the logs showed this as the 500 that is in reality being returned.